# One Root-Element or the whole layout in ReactDOM.render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i'm currently learing react.js and was wondering, if it's better to have my ReactDOM.render() like this (current status):

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="twelve columns">
        <Header />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="six columns">
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
      <div className="six columns">
        <Posts data={posts}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

or is it better to just have a root element like the following:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyPageRoot />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

and then add all the layout stuff (row, cols, etc) to the render()-method of MyPageRoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way does not give you any opportunity to define component state, or hook into lifecycle events. Also, the first way will eventually become very long as your application grows.

For these reasons, it's much more common to split your application into components, whether via `React.createClass`, `class extends React.Component` or just a pure function that returns some elements.